# Best way to display groups of data in one form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking to create a windows form.  This form is to display groups of data separately and I was aiming to do so in the same form window rather than have multiple windows open.

For example each group of data is defined by a Job#.  A user will want to review X different Job#'s at a time (Range would usually be 1-5, but could be more).  I would like to have 4 dataGridViews for each Job# plus various identifying and summed data in text boxes.  [Initial Example Concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pdox.jpg)

I was looking into using TabPages/Tab Controls.  My initial idea was to have a user click the different tabs to view the data for those jobs that they have pre-selected.  However these tabs don't seem to behave like classes from what I can see.  Is there perhaps a better way to go about this or some way to have the tabs act like classes?  So that each tab has a Job TextBox, 4 Different DataGridViews, etc.  So that I can easily create and display any number of jobs?

For example each Tab would have 4 dataGridViews, maybe 8 Text Boxes, Standardized Labels and a Standardized layout.

So would using tabs be a good idea?  Using some other WinForm control?

Comment: How does the user go about asking for these Jobs?  Is there a list?  They enter a number somewhere?  And once they've chosen, can they "close" a job?  I.e. does the list of "open jobs" need to be dynamically so as to automatically reconfigure the overall view as jobs come and go?

Comment: They would open up a search window type in a part number to filter out jobs then select each job that they want to view, probably with a double click.  I would have to send this info back to the first form.  I don't know if adding the ability to close jobs is critical.  Probably just removal all jobs to start fresh.  Jobs will not be dynamically added and removed.

Comment: Do you think the user will want/need to view more than one job at a time.  Say, for comparison of data between jobs?  Or do you intend to impose the "one job at a time" view, as in your model?

Comment: Unfortunately viewing multiple jobs at a time is not very feasible because one table will have at least 11 columns.  Screen space is an issue.  However adding a summary tab/control might be an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 solutions here:

1. Create a custom `Panel` holding all the controls you want (`TextBox`, `DataGridView`, ...), design it so that it looks best to you. Then add each of that `Panel` to each of `TabPage` of your `TabControl`.
2. Create a new custom `TabPage` and add the custom `TabPage` to your `TabControl.TabPages` instead of the standard `TabPage`.

I think the second approach can be done if you can initialize everything using code (not by drag-n-drop) because to get the `drag-n-drop` supported, you may need to write a custom `TabControl`. So the first approach is feasible and OK. You can replace the `Panel` by a `Form`, set the `Form.TopLevel = false`, you can add that form to any container control. Using `Form`, you can benefit the easiness of `drag-n-drop` to design and organize your controls.

Here is a little of code which may help you figure out:

```
public class TabPageClient : Form {
    public TabPageClient(){
        InitializeComponent();
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        TopLevel = false;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }
    //.... other code 
    //I think this is important
    //You should define some Properties and methods to control the data flowing into and out from your TabPageClient. 
    //You can also support some method to add/remove the controls dynamically.
}
```

Take the drag-n-drop requirement into account, I think using `UserControl` may be better:

```
public class TabPageClient : UserControl {
   public TabPageClient(){
      InitializeComponent();
      Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
   }
}
```

For `UserControl`, you should place the class in a separate *.cs file, compile your project and then you can see it in the `ToolBox` window (at the very top). Just drag and drop it like as other controls.

Comment: Hmm okay I am looking into panels.  I was thinking I would probably have to learn how to add controls using code alone for this to work.

Comment: @Matt even using `Panel`, you may still have to add controls by code, because we don't have a  dedicated `Design Surface` for a `Panel`, we just have a one for `Form` and `UserControl`. I think you can try `Form` instead, set its `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None` and `Form.TopLevel = false`. Then you can drag-n-drop the controls onto the form and use this form to add to your `TabPage`.

Comment: This suggestion might ultimately address some of the physical needs, but does nothing to aid in choosing the correct layout...in my opinion, the hardest part.  Design first, build second.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer grid-detail views.  Something we make heavy use of in our software.  The form has a `SplitContainer` in vertical alignment.

In the top panel, you add a list of some kind (`ListBox, ListView, DataGridView`...any control into which you can load a list and then react to selection).

In the bottom panel, you have yet more options.  Simplistically, you could use a `TableLayoutPanel` and then setup rows/columns to provide whatever arrangement of embedded controls you like, such as your array of grids to display data.  I suppose in keeping with your model, you'd have a single `ColumnStyle` and four (4) `RowStyles`.  Then in each row, add a grid.

This way, you keep it all in one place...one "screen", if you like (no tabs to flip through).  You react to the selection in the list to decide what data to display in the grids.  You then just need a bit of code (a class I would hope) that interfaces between the class(es) that provide the data, and the form controls that display it (the grids).

An additional benefit here is that with the list presentation, you can have a lot more than five (5) jobs in play at any one time.  In fact, with scrolling, as many as you like (not limited to the number of tabs before the display goes to pot).

Also, you would be re-using the grids.  Simply refreshing the displayed data for the list item selected.  You could even pre-load and cache it all if freshness is not an issue.

Also consider binding directly to data source if that's an option.

Comment: Hmm this sounds like an easy method to implement and yes it would be very easy to display a larger list of items to look through.  I wouldn't have to implement form objects through code, although I should probably become more familiar with that anyway.  Several arrays of 'dataTables' would work for this.

Comment: I would.  Frankly, I'm not a designer fan.  I get a lot more control out of adding controls in code, and it's a _lot_ more visible what's going on.  But you need some understanding of defaults for when you don't set something, because unlike the designer, you can't as easily see the defaults when you do it in code.  Choose your poison.  Also, don't be afraid of creating your own inherited controls when you want a little something extra.  DotNet makes it quite easy to make hay.

Comment: Also, since you're new at this...  `TableLayoutPanel` (and `Panels` in general) are very flexible controls.  You can put one inside the either, if you like.  Think of nested tables in HTML, for example.  Same concepts apply.  Controls inside controls, inside other controls.  As deeply as you care to go.  You can make some nice (if complicated) layouts.